# trying to get started with ng cli test implementation

Tags: angular

I created a new ng app with ng cli.  I'm trying to understand the test patterns for ng apps created with ng cli. I see a test.ts file defined in the app/src dir.  Looking at the code in test.ts, it looks like it looks for *.spec.ts files in the same-level src directory.

It looks like this test lookup path can be updated to point to a src/test dir. Is this most likely b/c I failed to accept some type of related option when I ng new'd the project? What should the test structure pattern look like? For example, src/tests dir with all tests or additional specialized subdirs within src/tests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular uses a wildcard search for **'*.spec.ts'** in any directory level, not just same-level as src directory. Therefore, you can put a test spec next to it's tested component or service, etc (a convention but you can store separately in say **'src/tests'** if desired).

If you only want to run certain specs, you can temporarily modify the line

```
const context = require.context('./', true, /\.spec\.ts$/);
```

For example, I often run a single file like

```
const context = require.context('./', true, /data.service.spec\.ts$/);
```